# How to prove that $\int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2 dx \geq \frac{2}{e^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, mean-value-theorem

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Suppose $f$ is a real, continuously differentiable function on $[0,1], f(0) = f(1) = 0,$ and $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)e^x dx = 1.$$ Prove that $(a) \int_{0}^{1} f'(x) e^x dx = -1,$ and

$(b) \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2 dx \geq \frac{2}{e^2}.$

My question is:

I know how to prove $(a)$ where I used integration by parts but I do not know how to solve $(b),$ should I use the mean value theorem or intermediate value theorem?

Can anyone help me in solving letter $(b)$ please?

Comment: Perhaps Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the integral of a). You wille even get ${2\over e^2-1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, you have

$$\begin{aligned}
1 &= \left\lvert \int_{0}^{1} f^\prime(x) e^x dx \right\rvert^2\\
&\le \int_{0}^{1} (f^\prime(x))^2 dx  \int_{0}^{1} e^{2x} dx\\
&= \left(\int_{0}^{1} (f^\prime(x))^2 dx\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}(e^2-1)\right)\\
&\le \left(\int_{0}^{1} (f^\prime(x))^2 dx\right) \frac{e^2}{2}
\end{aligned}$$

leading to the desired result.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it by IVT (intermediate value theorem) or MVT?

Comment: I have never seen before that $|\int|^2 \leq \int |.|^2$ I only know that this is true for $|.|$ not $|.|^2.$ do you have a proof for this please?

Comment: @MathIgnorance That's the cauchy schwarz inequality  -  it is applicable because $\displaystyle \int_0^1$ is an inner product on the vector space of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. Look it up, cauchy schwarz is a very important result!

Comment: I think your first line (equality) to second is not just Cauchy Schwartz because in C.S. the absolute value is inside the integral sign not outside it

Comment: @MathIgnorance No, what I wrote is Cauchy Schwartz inequality. See [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality?wprov=sfti1).